# Java how to set up SSL Connection client-server

Tags: java, ssl, client-server, ssl-certificate

I have looked around already and googled about this, but I haven't been able to find a definitive answer.

Currently I have all the basic code done to support an SSL connection between clients and my server, but I am lost on how to continue.

What I have:

- A game that uses the client-server model.
- I need to distribute clients at some point.
- I will have a server running on a fixed host/port.

In order to use SSL it seems that I need certificates, my questions:

- How do I get these certificates?
- How do I include them in the client and in the server?

Any answer will be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Hi @skiwi did you manage to solve this problem? I'm having the same experience. I found out that on my server I have to enable Certificates for my selected domains via "Lets Encrypt" in my cPanel, but now I'm stuck at the Java client side. Just experimneting with Http**s**URLConnection, but I'm not sure how this fits in with the certificates. Doesn't seem to be much online by way of example.

Comment: @Antinous Quite frankly I don't remember much of this question and I very much doubt that I continued implementing this idea, sorry that I'm not able to provide more help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html).

You only need one certificate for SSL, at the server, unless you are doing client authentication, which you haven't mentioned.